# How do I save an entire string as a txt file in Go?

Tags: string, go

I'm creating a simple word processing program in Go. From the command line, I have two prompts:

$Enter Title:

$Enter Body:

The program is supposed to save the document as a txt file and print it to the command line. The program works if the user user types in a one-word Title and a one-word Body. But if the user types in a several-word title, this will happen:

```
$Enter Title: Here is a title

$Enter Body: s

$  title

-bash: title: command not found
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

//Create struct for a document
type Document struct {
    Title string
    Body []byte
}

//Save document as txt file
func (p *Document) save() error {
    filename := p.Title + ".txt"
    return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, p.Body, 0600)
}

//Load document
func loadPage(title string) (*Document, error) {
    filename := title + ".txt"
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &Document{Title: title, Body: body}, nil
}

//Input document title and body. 
func main() {
    fmt.Print("Enter Title: ")
    var Title string
    fmt.Scanln(&Title)

    fmt.Print("Enter Body: ")
    var Body []byte
    fmt.Scanln(&Body)

//Save document and display on command line
    p1 := &Document{Title: Title, Body: []byte(Body)}
    p1.save()
    p2, _ := loadPage(Title)
    fmt.Println(string(p2.Body))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `bufio.ReadString` instead of `fmt.Scanln`?
Not 100% how Scanln works, but I am pretty sure the issue comes from a misuse of that function.
Example with bufio:

```
package main

import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
        "os"
        "strings"
)

// Document represent the document's data.
type Document struct {
        Title string
        Body  []byte
}

// Save dumps document as txt file on disc.
func (p *Document) save() error {
        filename := p.Title + ".txt"
        return ioutil.WriteFile(filename, p.Body, 0600)
}

// loadPage loads a document from disc.
func loadPage(title string) (*Document, error) {
        filename := title + ".txt"
        body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        return &Document{Title: title, Body: body}, nil
}

// Input document title and body.
func main() {
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Enter Title: ")
        title, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        title = strings.TrimSpace(title)

        fmt.Print("Enter Body: ")
        body, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        body = strings.TrimSpace(body)

        //Save document and display on command line
        p1 := &Document{Title: title, Body: []byte(body)}
        if err := p1.save(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        p2, err := loadPage(title)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(p2.Body))
}
```

Comment: wrt [`fmt.Scanln`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanln) it says "Scanln is similar to Scan, but stops scanning at a newline…"; so look at [`fmt.Scan`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scan) which says "Scan scans text read from standard input, storing **successive space-separated values** into successive arguments." So yeah, the OP effectively asked for the first word not the first line.